Naming of SAS block devices under /dev/disk/by-id?
When one uses SATA SSDs or HDDs under Linux, they can be addressed in numerous ways, like for example:
/dev/sda
/dev/disk/by-id/ata-TOSHIBA_MG05ACA800E_78LBK8P7FUUD
/dev/disk/by-id/wwn-0x50000398abc0251c

which, on my system, all refer to the same disk. I recently started to use a couple SAS disks of different make and model, and I noticed that these SAS disks seem to behave a bit different. For example
/dev/sdb
/dev/disk/by-id/scsi-35000cca01337732c
/dev/disk/by-id/wwn-0x5000cca01337732c

are also all the same disk. But I would have expected that there would also be a device file like, for example
/dev/disk/by-id/scsi-HGST_HUSSL4040BSS600_XWVZGT1A

so the format would be similar to the SATA disk, <interface>-<manufacturer>_<model>_<serial>. I would find this much more convenient. So I wonder, why are the SAS disks treated differently in this regard from other disks? even NVME disks have a similar device file with the manufacturer, model and serial number in its name, but not the SAS disks.
Bonus question: is it possible (with the aid of some udev rule?) to have these more informative device files also for the SAS disks?

Try to create a /etc/udev/rules.d/61-sas.rules (you may have some other name for it but make sure it's prefixed with a number larger than 60, because the necessary data is "imported" with a rule in 60-persistent-storage.rules):
ACTION!="remove", KERNEL=="sd*", ENV{ID_SCSI}=="1", ENV{ID_VENDOR}=="?*", ENV{ID_MODEL}=="?*", ENV{ID_SCSI_SERIAL}=="?*", SYMLINK+="disk/by-id/scsi-$env{ID_VENDOR}_$env{ID_MODEL}_$env{ID_SCSI_SERIAL}$env{.PART_SUFFIX}"

You may want to check with udevadm info /dev/sdb to find out what Es are available and which are the ones you want to use to form the link name first. The ENV matches / tests (except ENV{ID_SCSI}=="1") are paranoia tests that make sure the envs that are available and non-empty (I think). Not every env item is guaranteed to be available for every drive.
The main reason of the difference you see between (S)ATA and (SA)S(CSI) drives is because systemd/udev have different builtin programs to query for the "data" that may be useful, namely ata_id and scsi_id, because the two protocols use different command sets. The "data structure" is different too. For example, "model" returned in ATA IDENTIFY DEVICE is apparently composed of both the vendor name and the model number, and "unit serial number" (which is set as ID_SCSI_SERIAL) in the corresponding SCSI VPD page, if available, might have higher resemblance to serial number found in ATA IDENTIFY DEVICE data.
In 60-persistent-storage.rules, essentially one same rule is used to create the "bus" symlink for all types of "scsi disks" (sdX), and the name is formed with:
$env{ID_BUS}-$env{ID_SERIAL}$env{.PART_SUFFIX}


thanks. It works, but interestingly, the partitions are ignored, even though the .PART_SUFFIX is listed in the rule.

@T.Pluess hmm no idea. I tried to simulate the case with my UAS drive (by having a copy of 60-persistent-storage.rules in /etc/udev/rules.d/, with the rules that call ata_id and usb_id commented), the exact rule in my answer works for me in creating symlinks for both the drive and its partitions.

@T.Pluess One thing I could think of is that, perhaps somehow some of the ID_ envs matched by the rule you use was not imported from the disk to the partitions. (But in my tests, all those used in my rule, including but not limited to ID_SCSI, don't seem to have any problem in getting themselves imported, as of systemd 256.1 on Arch. Either way, you may check the partitions with udevadm info and see if the output gives you any idea.)
